# Android ViewPager of WebViews: Sourced js files inside a WebView are being ignored

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, android-viewpager

I have an activity that contains ViewPager of WebViews.
I load all the WebViews in the onCreate method and set the OffscreenPageLimit (of the ViewPager) to the number of the WebViews.
Every WebView loads the same html file and every html file contains reference to external js files and also embedded javascript code.

The first WebView manage to source the external js files correctly.
From the second WebView (when I go to the next page in the ViewPager), I can't run any javascript functions which are sourced by external js files (Seems like they aren't being included in the html).

Your help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!